# Opinion of tag "char-pointer"

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I don't think that [char-pointer](/questions/tagged/char-pointer) is a good tag.  On it's own it doesn't add any value to a question.  At best it should be merged into the [pointers](/questions/tagged/pointers), but I am in favor of removing it entirely.

As of writing this, there are only 19 questions.  Should it be removed? replaced? or leave it be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not a fan of this, it really doesn't add anything to the question and while not ambiguous, there are other tags which when used together make it much easier to search.

To that end I've gone and retagged the questions marked [char-pointer](/questions/tagged/char-pointer) with both [pointers](/questions/tagged/pointers) and [string](/questions/tagged/string), as every question in that tag was dealing with not a pointer to a single character, but multiple sequential characters, which are... erm...  strings.

I've also kept a list of the questions that were retagged.  If we really want them back or tagged differently, it's easily done.

As an aside, I'm also thinking the [const-char-pointer](/questions/tagged/const-char-pointer) tag questions (nine of them) should be retagged [const](/questions/tagged/const), [string](/questions/tagged/string) and [pointer](/questions/tagged/pointer).

Note, I've also removed the [const-char-pointer](/questions/tagged/const-char-pointer) and retagged as above.  I have that list as well.